# Angular animations working first time but won't run on subsequent calls

Tags: angular, animation

I'm trying to animate the colour of some numbers using Angular animations, I want the animations to change the colour of the numbers to green/red depending on if they've increased or decreased, then I want the colors to fade back to black after a couple seconds.

However this isn't working properly at all, for the first iteration of the animations they seem to work properly, however anything after the first animation means that the animations won't fire at all or some of them will fire, but not all of them will.

Sometimes some decrease animations fire properly, but in the same update other decrease animations won't fire, despite the value of differenceInPrice both being decrease. This happens for both increase and decrease.

```
 trigger('change', [
      transition('* => increase', [
        animate('5s', keyframes([
          style({color: '#0be000'}),
          style({color: '#0be000'}),
          style({color: 'black'})
        ]))
      ]),
      transition('* => decrease', [
        animate('5s', keyframes([
          style({color: 'red'}),
          style({color: 'red'}),
          style({color: 'black'})
        ]))
      ])
    ])
```

The animation itself is pretty simple, if the @change trigger changes from any state to 'increase', I run the keyframes to change to green. And likewise if the state changes to 'decrease' I run the keyframes to change to red. Nothing should happen if the state changes from * to neutral, so I haven't included an animation for that.

```
<td mat-cell #holdersCell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" [@change]="dataSource.data[i].differenceInPrice === 0 ? 'increase' : dataSource.data[i].differenceInPrice[i] === 1 ? 'decrease' : 'neutral'"> {{element.currentCount}} </td>
```

differenceInPrice for each dataSource element is set using the below method

```
compareDifferenceInPrice(newData: TokenData[], oldData: any[]){
    newData.forEach(token => {
      let newHolderCount = token.currentCount;
      let oldHolderCount = oldData.find(x => x.id === token.id).oldCount;

      token.differenceInPrice =  newHolderCount < oldHolderCount ? DifferenceInPriceEnum.Decrease :
        newHolderCount > oldHolderCount ? DifferenceInPriceEnum.Increase : DifferenceInPriceEnum.Neutral;

      console.log(`Difference ${token.name} - ${DifferenceInPriceEnum[token.differenceInPrice]} (${newHolderCount} ${oldHolderCount}`)
    });

    return newData;
  }
```

Which is ran by this refresh method which is called OnInit

```
refresh() {
    this._tokenService.tokenDataSubject.subscribe((tokenData: TokenData[]) => {
      if(this.oldCounts && this.oldCounts.length > 0){
        tokenData = this.compareDifferenceInPrice(tokenData, this.oldCounts);
      }
      this.dataSource.data = tokenData;

      this.oldCounts = [];
      tokenData.forEach(x => {
        this.oldCounts.push({
          id: x.id,
          oldCount: x.currentCount
        });
      })
    })
  }
```

Edit: I've done some more testing and it looks like the animations don't fire when the old state is the same as the new state. So if 'increase' changes to 'increase', is there anyway I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think this is what you're after, but one idea is to put everything through a intermediate transition state first, then apply the new state after a millisecond pause...

```
<td mat-cell #holdersCell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"  [@change]="doTrigger(i)"> {{element.currentCount}} </td>

doTrigger(i:number) {
 this.dataSource.data[i].differenceInPrice='nothing';
 setTimeout(()=>{
   this.dataSource.data[i].differenceInPrice === 0 ? 'increase' : 
   this.dataSource.data[i].differenceInPrice[i] === 1 ? 'decrease' : 'neutral';
  }, 20)
}
```